# Создать контактную форму (обратной связи) в WordPress c записью в БД MySQL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Стоит задача сделать форму обратной связи при условии, что данные формы должны записываться в БД, а на e-mail клиента также отправляется письмо (например "заявка получена"). Все нужно сделать посредством плагинов и бесплатно.

Нашла плагин *WPForms*, который позволяет это сделать, но только в платной версии. Аналогично с плагином *Contact Form 7 External Database*.

Буду благодарна если тот, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, поделится советом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) + [любой плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/contact+form+7+database/), который устроит.
Например  [CFDB7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/)

Comment: Благодарю, получилось!